# Postfix forward mail sent to own domain to gmail

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I have a domain "mydomain.com" with an SMTP (send-only) Postfix Server on it. For receiving, i use gmail. (MX Records are set to gmail)
Everything works fine with sending out mails, except when i try to send a mail to anymail@mydomain.com -> I think the server knows that *@mydomain.com is himself instead of looking up the MX records for where to actually send it.

How do i configure this properly? The Gmail mail is not an @gmail.com E-Mail, but also a @mydomain.com E-Mail. Is there a way to tell the server "Please still forward it to the MX Server Records"?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What is your Postfix configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Check the values of myhostname and mydestination parameters in /etc/postfix/main.cf.

myhostname should be set to the FQDN of your SMTP server. e.g.
myhostname = smtp.mydomain.com

mydestination parameter controls which domains Postfix considers local and will deliver the mail locally instead of forwarding it. In case of a SMTP only server you can set the mydestination parameter to something like:
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain, smtp.mydomain.com

In this case, mail for @mydomain.com will be forwarded to the MX (gmail).

You can find more inspiration here: http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html